# (RasPi) Trying to control 2 different water pumps with different relays

Tags: dc-motor, raspberry-pi, motor-controller

PS: This is for a school project and I'm not very experienced with electronics.

I'm trying to create a flush system. I need to control 2 different motors, it's a single iteration circuit with a timer, so every time a button is pressed motor A and motor B will turn on, after a set time motor A will turn off and so will motor B a little later. I'm trying to do this with relays and a RasPi. However, I don't have to use these.

I have a :

1. RasPI 3
2. 9V batteries (2)
3. SRD-12VDC-SL-C (2)
4. 12V DC motor (1)
5. 3V DC motor (1)

[image]

I want to ask will this circuit work? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Will the circuit work?

Comment: No it won't. On one hand you connect one relais to the positive node of the battery while the other is connected to the negative, they should both be connected to the positive in relation to a defined ground. On the otherhand you're completely shorting the lefthand side. Do your motors have a drive enable signal or just 2 wires?

Comment: Umm I dont know electronics, im still doing gcses. If you are free, could you help me out through discord?

Comment: I do not have discord.

Comment: @HamzaUmair - Welcome :-) I see that you are asking others to help you "off site" via discord. That is not the mission on Stack Exchange sites. Here, you ask a *single* question in each topic, which you have already researched to the best of your ability, and you include details of what you have done to try to solve your own problem. We don't allow open-ended topics where people add on "many more questions". If you cannot stick to one question per topic, you may need to find a forum which better suits your needs. Please read the [tour] and [help] to learn more. Consider [chat] on this site.

Comment: Ill check out the chat, thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Im going to delete this question and ask a more specific one

Comment: @HamzaUmair - "*Im going to delete this question*" Generally that's a bad plan, as explained [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) especially once you have answers, as you will be removing them too. Why would people want to help you, if you remove answers which they spent time researching, drafting and writing, and make them unavailable to future readers? See what I mean? You might, or might not even be *allowed* to delete it. IMHO you need to do much more research before asking another question, as your existing plan makes little sense :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The things you need to keep in mind are
1) Check the max voltage and current rating of each motor
2) make sure your supply is capable enough for producing enough amount of current when both the motors are working simultaneously and under full load as well as to be compatible with relay 
3) make sure the relays ratings of current and voltage lie within the range of power supply cause so as to avoid damaging.

For starters the standard batteries won't cut it. Meaning you need a power supply of high enough rating to drive the entire circuit apart from raspberry pi. If you meet all these conditions then the circuit will work successfully

Comment: If you are free, I have many more questions. discord?

Comment: Leave the questions here in the comment and I will get back to you when I can

Comment: RasPi uses 5V, is it ok if I use 18 Volts?

Comment: If you are taking about supplyin 18v at raspberry pi input the of course not..it will blow up

Comment: Further your raspi will not be able to drive your relais, you'll need additional drivers. I'd anyway use different once, these are 250V/15A way more than your motors will drain.

Comment: @Humpawumpa I don't think that would be necessary because raspberry pi is only used for switching the relay for which only the polarity needs to change . It has got nothing to do with current

Comment: Interesting,... but I'm pretty sure the datasheet states that at 5V coil voltage you'll have 71.4mA coil current

Comment: I have a 12volt 8watt water pump, and 2 6F22 9volt batteries connected together but they dont seem to turn the pump/motor

Comment: It needs more current . The batteries are not capable of supplying so much current. They can only create the specified voltage . Hence I said you need a better power supply. If my answer works for you please tap on

Comment: Tap on the tick mark below the up vote and down vote arrows

Comment: Can someone please explain as to why my answer has been downvoted?